# How to get element (text/content) path from an xml file using Python?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

Let's say the keyword I'm looking for is under root//parentNode//childNode1//childNode2//text, I want the output to be "The keyword you're looking for is under {xml_path_to_element}"

I couldn't find a method in the xml.etree.ElementTree documentation that does what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for a text pattern with **regex**:
Input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <parentNode>
    <childNode1>
      <childNode2>text</childNode2>
    </childNode1>
  </parentNode>
</root>
```

Program:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

tree = ET.parse("xpath.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

keyword = input("The keyword you're looking for? ")
tags = []
hit = False
while hit == False:
    for elem in root.iter():
        hit = re.match(keyword, elem.text)
        tags.append(elem.tag)
        
if hit != None:    
    print(f"The keyword '{keyword}' you're looking for is under{ {'/'.join(tags)} }")
else:
    print(f"The keyword '{keyword}' you're looking for not found!")
```

Output:

```
The keyword you're looking for? text
The keyword 'text' you're looking for is under{'root/parentNode/childNode1/childNode2'}
```

Comment: Thank you! However I'm getting the error "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object", I tried applying python str but the issue persists

Comment: Have you used my code and input file? Interpreter said you which line you have a failure.